# MVC3 shopping cart with dynamic value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, shopping-cart

I am following this tutorial; http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8

In my project, I want to pass the rental price which is radio button value instead of 'Price'.

How do I pass the radiobutton value for cart with using ajax?

Here is my source details..could you tell me how to pass the radiobutton value with ajax?

I am stock from last 2 weeks really.. I need to your help.

Thanks.

[MVC3 passing the radioButton value for shopping cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071741/mvc3-passing-the-radiobutton-value-for-shopping-cart)

Comment: All of this is in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you are going to be able to create a decent MVC app by hacking the MVC Music Store without understanding it.

If you go back and actually do / redo the tutorial then I'm sure you will be able to answer your own question.

The [link you provided](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8) shows

1) How to form post to AddToCart

2) How to post via Ajax in RemoveFromCart

So all you need to do is change AddToCart Controller and View to use the Ajax Post (like RemoveFromCart) and include the selected radio buttons Price value in the post to the controller.

It's all there in the tutorial.

Good Luck!